# Postback in asp.net: hiding or showing a control based on session variable?

Tags: asp.net, postback

In my markup for the page I have the following div:

```
   <div id="utteranceFilterSection" runat="server" enableviewstate="true">
        <asp:Label ID="lblShowFilterPrompt" runat="server" Text="Show: "></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDetailsFilter" 
            AutoPostBack="true"
            runat="server" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDetailsFilter_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="All">All</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Pass">Passed</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Fail">Failed</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Blocked">Blocked</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
```

I'd like to show or hide this div based on the contents of my session state. In Page_Load I have:

```
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
       //if (this.Session["ShowFilterControl"] != null)
        //{
        //    this.utteranceFilterSection.Visible = true;
        //    this.Session.Remove("ShowFilterControl");
        //}
        this.utteranceFilterSection.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        this.utteranceFilterSection.Visible = false;
    }
```

Setting visible works fine if I use the uncommented postback code, however, if I try to do it using the commented out code, I see the code step through in the debugger but the div does not become visible. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have sessionstate enabled for the page?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to set a bool and evaluate that in the if statement along with the postback condition? like this:

```
bool showFilter = (bool)this.Session["ShowFilterControl"];
if (Page.IsPostBack &&  showFilter)
    {
       this.Session["ShowFilterControl"] = false;
       this.utteranceFilterSection.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        this.utteranceFilterSection.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: I guess I miss the cast

Comment: but the main point I wanted to made is that it would be better if you evaluate both conditions in the same sentence